# How to use parents model fields in the model form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I use django 1.9 and have some inheritance of models e.g.:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

After that I use this model to add `created` and `modified` into my models. But I can't use this fields into the forms. E.g.:

```
class Customer(TimeStampedModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True,
                                  null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True,
                                 null=True, default=None)
```

And the form code:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Customer
         fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'modified')
         readonly_fields = ('modified', )
```

And I get an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (modified) specified for ...
```

How can I add this field to the form? I have it in the DB schema but django form doesn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto_now=True` fields are automatically update when you call `Model.save()`.
for more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#datefield
auto_now=True fields can't be access from ModelForm,
As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no way to show it? I don't want to change it but show.

Comment: auto_now = True field is not available in forms. Because form is for editing values. So do one thing that create an html input and pass current_time `<input id="id_time" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="form-control"  name="time" placeholder="time" value="{% now "m-d-Y H:i:s" %}">`. This will show the current time in your template.

Answer (score 1):

the problem in occurring because you are using 1.9 , this was changed from 1.10

so you can update you django version so that you can use this